# Cordova 'browser' platform network unavailable

Tags: cordova, networking, browser

Testing a Cordova app, I have added the platform browser with:

```
cordova platform add browser
```

Now when testing I am using:

```
cordova run browser
```

It launches an instance of Chrome (OS X) and I get this in the console:

```
adding proxy for Device
adding proxy for NetworkStatus

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.google.com/. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on 
the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' 
is therefore not allowed access.
```

Any subsequent attempts for the app to access Internet resources fail silently with nothing appearing in Network Activity (in the Chrome inspector).

`Cordova -v` gives me `5.3.1`

I have added the plugin `cordova-plugin-whitelist` and added these lines to my config.xml:

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<access origin="*" />
```

It works fine on Android and iOS, testing on real devices using USB debugging and in the iOS simulator.

Firstly - what is trying to contact google.com? There are no references to google.com in my code.

And secondly, why can the app not connect to the network?

Comment: is your issue resolved?

Comment: Not for Cordova 5.3.1. However updating to Cordova 6.0.0 seems to have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Updating to Cordova 6.0.0 seems to have resolved the problem. I can't explain why there was a problem originally though.

Comment: Likely you were using a new plugin with 5.3.1. If you used an earlier version of the plugin, then it would likely work.